# Estimating the Poisson distribution

Tags: r, distribution

I have a graph and I calculated the degree distribution and degree as follows:

```
library(igraph) # for these two functions

dd <- degree_distribution(graph) 
d <- degree(graph)
```

From this, I estimated to Power Law, to see if my distribution follows the "Law of Power":

```
degree = 1:max(d)
probability = dd[-1]

nonzero.position = which(probability != 0)
probability = probability[nonzero.position]
degree = degree[nonzero.position]

reg = lm(log(probability) ~ log(degree))
cozf = coef(reg)

power.law.fit = function(x) exp(cozf[[1]] + cozf[[2]] * log(x))
```

From that, I plotted the points and power law using `ggplot2`.
Resulting in the following image:

```
df <- data.frame(x = degree, y = probability)
  print(
      ggplot(df, aes(x,y,colour="Distribuição"))+
        geom_point(shape = 4) +
        stat_function(fun = power.law.fit, geom = "line", aes(colour="Power Law"))+

        labs(title = "Grafo", subtitle = "Distribuição dos Graus",
             x="K", y="P(k)", colour="Legenda")+
        scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")
  )
```

[image: PowerLaw and Data]

As you can see, my distribution does not follow Power Law! I would like to estimate the Poisson distribution and plot on the same graph.
Even though I'm not sure that my distribution does not follow (or follow) Poisson, I would like to draw it together with Power Law. I have no idea how to estimate this distribution (Poisson) from the data, and calculate the average degree.

Can anyone help me?

> The graph used to calculate the distribution and the degree is very large (700 thousand vertices), so I did not put the data of the graphs. The explanation of the answer can be based on any graph.

Comment: You may wish to reference these answers from Cross Validated on fitting distributions to data in R: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51470/finding-appropriate-distribution-that-fit-to-for-a-frequency-distribution-of-a-v, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best

Comment: Good answer! I'll check out!

Comment: maybe relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071855/trying-to-fit-poisson-distribution-in-r-using-fitdistr-to-erdos-reyni-random-gra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?dpois`:

> The Poisson distribution has density
>
> *p(x) = λ^x exp(-λ)/x!*
>
> for *x = 0, 1, 2, …* . The mean and variance are *E(X) = Var(X) = λ*.

So I'll generate some dummy data with a secret lambda:

```
mysecret <- ####

x <- data.frame(xes = rpois(50, mysecret))
```

> ```
> > x$xes
>  [1] 0 2 2 1 1 4 1 1 0 2 2 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 2 4 2 1 0 3 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 0 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 2 0 3 2 2 2 3
>
>
> > mean(x$xes)
> [1] 1.66
> > var(x$xes)
> [1] 1.371837
> ```

So two good guesses for my secret lambda are 1.66 and 1.37. Let's try them:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x, aes(xes)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density.., color = "Raw data"), 
                 fill = "white", binwidth = 1, center = 0, size = 1.5) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = dpois, aes(x = xes, y = xes, color = "Density based on E(X)"), 
               fun.args = list(lambda = 1.66), geom = "line", size = 1.5) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = dpois, aes(x = xes, y = xes, color = "Density based on Var(X)"), 
               fun.args = list(lambda = 1.37), geom = "line", size = 1.5)
```

[image]

They're both pretty good. You can't really use the built-in `stat_function` or `geom_density` for generating these, since Poisson distributions are only defined for integers. The histogram and summary functions work well though, since they're only estimated at the data points themselves, not interpolated.

If you want more detail, you can use the `MASS` package:

```
MASS::fitdistr(x$xes, dpois, start = list(lambda = 1))
```

> ```
>     lambda  
>   1.6601563 
>  (0.1822258)
> ```

So let's try constructing from that:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(xes = seq.int(max(x$xes)+1)-1,
                 dens.m = dpois(xes, 1.66),
                 dens.u = dpois(xes, 1.66+0.18),
                 dens.l = dpois(xes, 1.66-0.18))
```

> ```
> > df
> # A tibble: 6 x 4
>     xes     dens.m     dens.u     dens.l
>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
> 1     0 0.19013898 0.15881743 0.22763769
> 2     1 0.31563071 0.29222406 0.33690378
> 3     2 0.26197349 0.26884614 0.24930880
> 4     3 0.14495866 0.16489230 0.12299234
> 5     4 0.06015785 0.07585046 0.04550717
> 6     5 0.01997240 0.02791297 0.01347012
> ```

```
ggplot(x, aes(xes)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), color = "black",
                 fill = "white", binwidth = 1, center = 0, size = 1.5) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df, aes(xes, ymin = dens.l, ymax = dens.u), fill = "grey50", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(xes, dens.m, color = "Based on E(X)\n+/-1 SD of lambda"), size = 1.5)
```

[image]

Based on these two methods and visual interpretation, you should feel comfortable saying λ = 1.66+/-0.18.

For reference, my secret initial value was 1.5.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, the original analysis looks at probability as a function of degree, i.e. a regression analysis with degree as a predictor - I don't think this kind of distribution-fitting incorporates predictors so it may not be suited to the same kind of regression analysis.

Comment: @Marius I agree, but we were given no actual data to work with, so this is how to estimate a Poisson distribution (the stated question) not how to do regression on a Poisson GLM (possibly the desired outcome).

Comment: This plot is the distribution of degrees. I would like to plot, as well as Barabasi (http://barabasi.com/networksciencebook/chapter/3#degree-distribution - image 3.4 and 3.5)

Comment: @Fillipe Your link leads to "404 page not found".

Comment: Sorry. First > http://barabasi.com/networksciencebook, Section 3 (random network) and subsection 3.4(Image 3.4 and 3.5)

Comment: I have the data (degree distribution). What I need is plot the poisson distribution, only!

Comment: `degree(graph)`, your vector `d` is equivalent to the vector I made called `x$xes`.

Comment: But, it's possible estimate the perfect λ ? Because you estimate λ = 1.5. There is any function, in R, that show me the perfect λ, based in my data?

Comment: My initial 1.5 was just to generate some data, since you didn't give us any to work with. The methods I showed are how you estimate lambda from a univariate sample of integers.

Comment: Ok. I'll check out!